# airflow git-sync not refreshing dags when new dags are pushed to git repo

Tags: git, kubernetes, airflow

I am using airflow on Kubernetes, with git-sync option for DAGS deployment. When there is a new DAGs pushed to our git repo, it airflow is not updating new DAGs until we restart scheduler pod. is there any other way to update the DAGs without restarting scheduler pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

resolved this issue using git-sync sidecar container.

there is an  `extraContainers:` option in values.yaml file. we can add kubernetes git-sync as a sidecar container to continuously sync from git.

```
extraContainers: 
  ## Additional containers to run alongside the Scheduler, Worker and Web pods
  ## This could, for example, be used to run a sidecar that syncs DAGs from object storage.
   - name: git-sync
     image: k8s.gcr.io/git-sync:v3.1.1
     volumeMounts:
      - name: ssh-key
        mountPath: /var/ssh
      - name: known-hosts
        mountPath: /var/knownhosts
      - name: git-sync-volume
        mountPath: /tmp/git

     env:
      - name: GIT_SYNC_REPO
        value: git@gitlab.example.com/test.git
      - name: GIT_SYNC_DEST
        value: git
      - name: GIT_SYNC_WAIT
        value: "10"
      - name: GIT_SYNC_SSH
        value: "true"
      - name: GIT_SSH_KEY_FILE
        value: /var/ssh/sshkey
      - name: GIT_SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE
        value: /var/knownhosts/known_hosts
  ## Additional volumeMounts to the main containers in the Scheduler, Worker and Web pods.
  extraVolumeMounts: 
     # - volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/ssh"
            name: ssh-key
            readOnly: true
          - mountPath: "/var/knownhosts"
            name: known-hosts
            readOnly: true
          - name: git-sync-volume
            mountPath: /tmp/git

  extraVolumes: 
     #- volumes:
        - name: ssh-key
          secret:
            secretName: dags-secret
            items:
            - key: key
              path: sshkey
        - name: known-hosts
          secret:
            secretName: dags-secret
            items:
            - key: known_hosts
              path: known_hosts

        - name: git-sync-volume
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you could use [**Jenkins**](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins).

[With Jenkins](https://www.solita.fi/en/blogs/why-we-switched-to-apache-airflow/) it's easier to manage the automatic generation of dags,release them between environments and automatically menage versioning.

You wouldn't have to use scheduler then

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. We have deployed airflow on kubernetes using airflow stable helm chart. adding jenkins to the setup would make it more complex. Could you please suggest any other way other than using Jenkins

Comment: Meaby use CronJob?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: is there any other way without restarting the scheduler? I am saw few git-sync init containers for auto sync but they are not working with stable helm deployment.

Comment: Hi @user2416, may I ask you which stable release are you using? In the official helm chart the deployment is using git-clone "initContainers" while you are using git-sync right?
In my case, git-clone does not work with private github repo.
Thank you in advance

Comment: @PistolPete i am using helm chart version 3.0.2. I am able to connect to private git repo using git secret. I am using the official git-clone initContainer only. But my issue is dags are not being synced from git to airflow until we restart the airflow scheduler